# Unable to locate package GLFW on Linux Mint

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw

I have been trying to install GLFW and GLFW3, using Terminal to install

`sudo apt-get install GLFW`

`sudo apt-get install GLFW3`

Whenever I do so, I get results such as

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package glfw3`

I have been trying to install GLFW for two hours now, and I'm getting a bit impatient. Also I'm very new to Linux (Mint), so I apologize if I'm doing something stupid...

EDIT:
No matter what I try, my program encounters

`/home/myusername/Desktop/basic_window.cpp:11:21: fatal error: GL/glfw.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glfw.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.`

Having a frustrating time with this, not sure why this is much more complicated than the other libraries I've installed so far.

Comment: `apt-cache search glfw3`. Linux Mint might not even have version 3 yet.

Comment: Doesn't appear that it does. Is there no way to install it?

Answer (score 3):

> I have been trying to install GLFW and GLFW3, using Terminal to install...

On Mint 17, it looks like you need to install `libglfw2`. So perform a `sudo apt-get install libglfw2`.

If you plan on developing against it, then install `libglfw-dev` instead. Notice the lack of a version number.

If interested, perform `apt-cache search glfw`

Comment: `g++ ~/Desktop/basic_window.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -libglfw-dev -o ./Desktop/Projects`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libglfw-dev`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: `libglfw-dev` is the package name. Use `libglfw` or `libglfw2` when linking. You can `ls` `/usr/lib` to see which it is. Also, you usually omit the `lib` prefix when linking with `-l`.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu and Mint, library packages typically have names that begin with "lib", and development headers (for compiling new programs that use the library) are in a separate package whose name ends with "-dev".

Ubuntu 14.04 has GLFW 2 packaged as [libglfw2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglfw2) and [libglfw-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglfw-dev).  Mint doesn't seem to have those packages, but you can probably use the Ubuntu ones since Mint 17 is based on Ubuntu 14.04.

GLFW 3 isn't in Ubuntu 14.04, but it looks like it'll be in 14.10 (as [libglfw3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libglfw3) and [libglfw3-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libglfw3-dev)).

Unless you *really* need GLFW 3 specifically, you're probably better off sticking with the packaged GLFW 2.  Packages get easy automatic upgrades; compiling stuff "by hand" is a good way to end up with lots of cruft in your system with no automatic upgrade or uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

- [Download GLFW source packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/postdownload?source=dlp) from their website.
- Extract the folder `glfw-3.0.4` from the tarball
- Open console
- Navigate to the folder you just extracted and go inside of it using `cd`
- Type `cmake .` (be sure you include the dot)

If `cmake .` fails, then type the following as root:

- `apt-get install cmake`

If you don't think you're root then type the following:

- `sudo apt-get install cmake`

If that doesn't work then type the following as root, or add `sudo` if you're not root:

- `apt-get install build-essential cmake`

Once you have `cmake` installed, navigate back to the folder and try `cmake .` again.

Comment: I did this, and it says `-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Using X11 for window creation
-- Using GLX for context creation
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/trg/Desktop/glfw-3.0.4`

Comment: Still cannot build my program that is importing GLFW3.h. `g++ ~/Desktop/basic_window.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lGLFW -o ./Desktop/Projects`

Comment: Just uninstall what I said to install and listen to @jww

Comment: I had to install the following extra packagesbefore i could compile GLFW: cmake, libxrandr-dev, doxygen, libxinerama-dev, libxcursor-dev. This is on a Linux Mint 17 Mate.

Comment: Same additional libsas had to be installed for me to @Lightbulb1 for future reference for people, `sudo apt-get install -y doxygen libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev`